# Search Results display wrong file name attribute

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

My search results web part display some of my documents name correct and for some other documents the name is wrong, instead it displays other properties than the file name.

Example, if I search on the word "test" it displays my 3 documents named "test1","test2","test3". But for "test1" and "test3", the file name is the third header inside the document instead of the file name.

Comment: Please, provide some more details and some examples

Comment: Is it showing the Document Title?

Answer (score 1):

OOTB SharePoint search crawls the document (if it is a document) and Shows the Document´s Title as Title in the search result, it does not make a difference what you select in the managed-Properties or what you insert in the item´s title.